# How to draw organometallic compounds?

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

I'm trying to draw this molecule using the chemfig package but honestly don't know where or how to start. Please help. Thank you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setcrambond{3pt}{}{}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{
  ?[a]>[:18,.8]-[:108,.8]-[4]
    (
      -[:-40,.65,,,draw=none]@{r1}-[2,,,,dotted]
      Fe
      -[2,,,,dotted]@{r2}-[:-130,.7,,,draw=none]
      ?[b]-[,,,,line width=3.5pt]>[:72,.8]-[:162,.8]-[:-162,.8]?[b,4]
    )
  -[:-108,.8]?[a,4]}
\chemmove{
  \draw (r1) ellipse (15pt and 8pt);
  \draw (r2) ellipse (15pt and 8pt);
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, please show us what you have tried so-far. This is not a `just-do-it-for-me` site.

Comment: Since you are asking for a starting point, here are two; the chemfig manual and a google picture search for `site:tex.stackexchange.com  chemfig compounds`.

Comment: The example on p. 68 of the chemfig user guide seems to contain all necessary components

Comment: Is that better? @Raaja

Comment: You already got my +1 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\setchemfig{cram width=4pt}
\chemfig{
    ?[start]<[::-30]>[::+60]?[start]% Bottom ring
    -[::120,,,,draw=none]% Invisible bond
    M(-[:-90,0.7,,,dashed,preaction={draw=white,line width=3pt}])% Dashed bond with white border
    (-[:90,0.7,,,dashed])% Invisible bond
    -[::0,,,,draw=none]?[end]<:[:+30]>:[::-60]?[end]% Upper ring
}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you! That worked!